# convert boost::iostream::stream<boost::iostreams::source> to std::istream

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, boost-iostreams

I would like to expose streams in my code as their standard equivalents to eliminate user dependency on `boost::iostreams`.
Would like to do this efficiently of course without creating a copy if necessary. I thought about just setting the `std::istream`'s buffer to the one being used by the `boost::iostream::stream<boost::iostreams::source>`, however, this could cause ownership problems.
How do you convert `boost::iostream` to `std::iostream` equivalent?
Particularly `boost::iostream::stream<boost::iostreams::source>` to `std::istream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No conversion is needed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f0688d3bdf00d80)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

void foo(std::istream& is) {
    std::string line;
    while (getline(is, line)) {
        std::cout << " * '" << line << "'\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf[] = "hello world\nbye world";
    io::array_source source(buf, strlen(buf));
    io::stream<io::array_source> is(source);

    foo(is);
}
```

Other than that I don't think you could have ownership issues, since `std::istream` doesn't assume ownership when assigned a new rdbuf:

- [Why doesn't std::istream assume ownership over its streambuf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083163/why-doesnt-stdistream-assume-ownership-over-its-streambuf)

So, you're also free to do:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1b03985260dd6dd)</kbd>**

```
std::istream wrap(is.rdbuf());
foo(wrap);
```

Printing the same